# When I run command phpunit in terminal, I got php warning

Tags: laravel, laravel-testing

When I run a `phpunit` command in terminal console, I got Php warning.

I've tried to run `vendor/bin/phpunit` but the result is the same.

This is an error:

> PHP Warning:  "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did 
>    you mean to use "continue 2"? in D:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php 
>    on line 277
>    Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean 
>    to use "continue 2"? in D:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php on line 
>    277
>    PHP Warning:  "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you 
>    mean to use "continue 2"? in D:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php on 
>    line 285
>
> Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean 
>    to use
>    "continue 2"? in D:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php on line 285
>    PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Answer (score 0):

PHPUnit 3.7.21 was released in July 2013, meanwhile PHP has been improved and there was some changes in the codebase.

I suggest you to update PHPUnit for your project.

BTW if you google your error you can find a lot of discussion on that topic.

Comment: I solved this problem. I didn't know the right command for testing my ExampleTest.php.